# SignalR typescripf declaration file

Tags: signalr, typescript

I've started using typescript, easily found declaration (d.ts) files for angular.js and jquery. Can't find one for SignalR jquery though.

Can you guys help me. I could just create an interface that `extends JQuery` but somehow it's not working...

```
var hub = $.connection.myHub
```

it's complaining about `connection` thing... says "The property 'connection' doesn't exist on value of type 'JQueryStatic'"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) has a complete TypeScript definition for SignalR.

*Just updated the link, thanks Stuart*

Comment: Does anybody have examples of how to use Definitely Typed's def with Typescript?

Comment: James, you just need to reference in you code the files you want to use.

Comment: above link is not working, this one does https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 8):

This is what I was able to prepare in a quick and dirty way. Be aware that its probably barely correct, but its enough for me right now, and it seems to work as intended.

It might be a nice thing to start with. Lets call it "jquery.signalR-0.5.3.d.ts":

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
interface Hub {
    id: string;
    state: any;
    start(options?: any, callback?: () => any): JQueryPromise;
}

interface SignalR {    
    log(msg: string, logging: bool): void;
    isCrossDomain(url: string): bool;
    changeState(connection: any, expectedState: number, newState: number): bool;
    isDisconnecting(connection: any): bool;

    hub: Hub;
    connection: HubConnection;

    init(url, qs, logging): void;
    ajaxDataType: string;
    logging: bool;
    reconnectDelay: number;
    state: any;
    start(options?: any, callback?: () => any): JQueryPromise;
    starting(callback?: () => any): SignalR;
    send (data): SignalR;
    sending (callback?: () => any): SignalR;
    received (callback?: (data) => any): SignalR;
    stateChanged (callback?: (data) => any): SignalR;
    error (callback?: (data) => any): SignalR;
    disconnected (callback?: () => any): SignalR;
    reconnected (callback?: () => any): SignalR;
    stop (async? : bool): SignalR;
}

interface HubConnection extends SignalR {
    hub: Hub;
}

// extend JQuery interface
interface JQueryStatic {
    signalR: SignalR;
    connection: SignalR;
}
```

then you might want to define contract for your hub:

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.signalR-0.5.3.d.ts" />

interface IMyHub extends HubConnection {
    // your methods definition here
}

// extend SignalR interface
interface SignalR {
    myHub: IMyHub;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Self-plug]

I have created a tool to generate TypeScript declaration files for your hubs, methods and the types you pass between the client and the server. It includes the latest DefinitelyTyped signalr.d.ts file as well. I released an alpha version as a nuget package: SignalR.TypeScript. To install this package, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package SignalR.TypeScript -Pre
```

More information and how-to on my blog: http://murat.girg.in/2013/11/introducing-signalr-typescript/

[/Self-plug]

Answer (score 2):

Did it like that:

```
interface signalR extends JQueryStatic {
     connection;
}

var hub = (<signalR>$).connection.myHub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but if you need to move pure signalR javascript to Typescript quickly you can use an interface like this (you'll still need to include signalr.d.ts type definition).

```
interface SignalR {
    messageHub: any;
}

var chat = $.connection.messageHub;
chat.client.actionMessage = function (data) {
    console.info("actionMessage: received: message: " + data.message);
};
```